# How to serve the right mime type for a blazor site on ubuntu nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, blazor, webassembly

I have built a blazor webassembly site which I host on an ubuntu server using nginx. The configuration of the site in nginx is like this:

```
server {
    server_name  app.mysite.local;
    root         /srv/sites/app.mysite.local;
    index        index.html;
}
```

I published the site using visual studio to a local folder and copied the /dist folder to the root of /srv/sites/app.mysite.local. The site is now working on app.mysite.local but I get the folowing error messages:

WASM: wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

WASM: falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation

I tried adding 'application/wasm wasm' to the files /etc/mime.types and /etc/nginx/mime.types and restarted the server but without any effect. I don't know if these error messages are connected.

What I also noticed is when I go to /account/companyname using the menu on the index page, the page is displayed but I when I type the url app.mysite.local/account/companyname in the address bar I get an nginx 404 error. Maybe this is solved when I solve the mime type issue but I don't know that for sure.

Can anybody help me solving the mime type issue? Let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't use the dist folder:
You should publish the application using `dotnet publish -c Release` and copy the folder *bin\Release\netstandard2.1\publish\wwwroot* to */srv/sites/app.mysite.local*

The *nginx.conf* should be:

```
events { }
http {
    include mime.types;
    types {
        application/wasm wasm;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /srv/sites/app.mysite.local;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```